# Max no of lines for php files in Zend Framework 1.4 Model and Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

Does any one know the maximum no of lines allowed in zend framework1.4 for the controller and model PHP files.Do i need to split if the maximum no of lines exceed in php files.

Comment: Why would there be a maximum? The size of classes should be limited by common sense - huge classes will likely be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Tim Fountain thanks for your reply.I have one controller class with lot of actions and it's around more than 2000 lines of code.Does it cause any problem, So kindly advice what's need to be done.